# Sort by multiple columns not breaking previous columns order

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

**I have following columns (properties)**: Date, Name, Time.

**Data types:** `DateTime Date; string Name; TimeSpan Time;`

I need to apply a custom sorting depending on these three properties. My current code looks something like this:

```
var sortedData = data.OrderBy(x => x.Date)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
        .ThenBy(x => x.Date.TimeOfDay);
```

The problem with this solution is that it makes a huge mess. Dates are now in mixed order, also the names. Only the time is sorted as it should because it was the last property that was being sorted.

What I want to achieve is: 
**Rule 1:** First, all rows are sorted by `Date` column (Ascending) 
**Rule 2:** Then sorts by `Name` column only if next rows `Date` column is equal 
**Rule 3:** Then sorts by `Time` column only if next rows `Date` is equal AND  next rows `Name` starts with the same letter or it's position in alphabet is smaller.

The main idea is not break already sorted columns. How could I implement this solution?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. The point of `ThenBy` is to preserve the higher order. Are you sure you are doing what you think? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: @NetMage Yes, you are right.. I thought this is strange, this was my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you want sort by date (without time), then by name, then by time in a day. Please try  this code:

```
var sortedData = data.OrderBy(x => x.Date.Date)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Date.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: Actually, this makes sense.. Now I remember, I did some refactoring and I may have removed 'Date.Date'. This is sooo bad :D Thanks, I created test data and could reproduce this behavior.